# remove done as parameter

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have the following test:

```
   it('should call the backend to update a user', (done) => {
      const testUser = createUserFrom({
        iamId: '12',
        firstName: 'firstName',
        lastName: 'lastName',
        group: UserGroup.USER,
        email: 'abc@web.de',
        password: '12345678',
      });
      classUnderTest.updateUser(testUser).subscribe((res) => {
        expect(res).toMatchObject(testUser);
        done();
      });

      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(usersManagementUrl);
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('PUT');
      expect(req.request.body).toEqual(testUser);
      req.flush(testUser);
      httpTestingController.verify();
    });
  });
```

I want to remove done as parameter due to -> [no-done-callback](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/main/docs/rules/no-done-callback.md) and use other approach.

With async/await it is not working properly.

```
it('should call the backend to update a user', async () => {
      const testUser = createUserFrom({
        iamId: '12',
        firstName: 'firstName',
        lastName: 'lastName',
        group: UserGroup.USER,
        email: 'abc@web.de',
        password: '12345678',
      });
      await classUnderTest.updateUser(testUser).subscribe((res) => {
        expect(res).toMatchObject('WHATEVER');
      });

      const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(usersManagementUrl);
      expect(req.request.method).toEqual('PUT');
      expect(req.request.body).toEqual(testUser);
      req.flush(testUser);
      httpTestingController.verify();
    });
  });
```

In the example above of async/await in the expect I am using 'WHATEVER' instead of testUser and the test result is successful too, and that cannot be.

Comment: Why `async/await` doesn't work? What error did you get? Besides, you should provide a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: @slideshowp2 example added. The test is successful and it should no be if async/await would work properly.

Comment: Are you sure the callback of `subscribe` is invoked? Also, does `subscribe` really returning a `promise`?

Comment: @Christian if I write a console.log('something') after the first expect, I can only see it if the expect is true, if not, I cannot see it. But in both cases, when I run the test with IntelliJ, the test pass.

Comment: I don't think this is related to async/await. What happens if you instead of `toMatchObject` do `toBe`?

Comment: @Christian exactly the same

Comment: And 'something' is printed out to the console?

Comment: @Christian only when the expect returns true, if false, nothing is printed